# Cannot find module created with Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I use Browserify and Gulp to bundle JavaScript modules. I have one module which I generate with the following code:

```
browserify("./index.js", {
        standalone: "lib1"
      })
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source("lib1.js"))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('DEST'));
```

Index.js file contains the following code:

```
module.exports = require('./lib/lib1.js');
```

Then I have a second module which imports the previous one and works fine. I bundle the second module using the following code

```
browserify("./index.js", {
        standalone: "lib2"
      }).external('lib1')
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source("lib2.js"))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('DEST'));
```

If I import both modules in a browser I get an error in the second one indicating that it cannot find module `lib1`. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

In the browser I import first `lib1` and them `lib2`

```
<script src='lib1.js'></script>
<script src='lib2.js'></script>
```

Comment: `module.exports = require('./lib/ lib1.js');` is the space in the path intentional? Also, isn't the job of browserify to bundle all modules into a single script?

Comment: No, it is a mistake. I fixed it on the question. I don’t want to bundle the modules. I want to use module lib1 on lib2.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem with a downgrade of Gulp 4 to Gulp 3. This is not a satisfactory solution.

In Gulp 3 I use the following code to generate the second file:

```
browserify("./index.js", {
      standalone: "lib2"
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source("lib2.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('DEST'));
```

Using Gulp 3 I can import both libraries and it works fine.